# What is a measure of the rapidity of change in a random variable?

Tags: limits, random-variables, definition, standard-deviation

This question appeared in the GATE exam 2006 ICE paper.

[image: Question]
[image: Options]

The solution given is, [image: madeeasy solution]

I don't see how that the integral is the SD of $f(t)$ even if we assume mean is 0 and it's defined over the entire real line, I think the SD would look like,

$$\left [\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (t-\mu)^2 f(t)dt \right ]^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Now of the options only that one looks like a SD, so atleast I hope to understand what standard deviation has to do with "rapidity of change". I thought I understood SD well, it's a measure of dispersion. It tells us how spread out the random variable is.

So please tell me what is a good measure of the rapidity of change in a random variable.

Comment: I disagree with all answers. Take $f(t)=10^6$ for all $t$, which has no change whatsoever: None of those metrics give a change of 0.  I observe that c is the square root of b so both are essentially measuring the same thing.

Comment: I observe that the integrals in (a)-(c) are the same when $f(t)$ is replaced by $f(ct)$ for $c>0$, where $c$ can be used to slow down or speed up time, and so these integrals have nothing to do with "rapidity of change." (a) could be viewed as a sample path mean, (b) could be viewed as a sample path variance (under the assumption that the mean is zero). I also interpret $f(t)$ as a function of $t$ (it does not make sense to call it a random variable).  Your last paragraph seems to be interpreting it as a density and I don't think that is the intention of the problem.

Comment: @Michael I think f(t) is a probability measure so it can't be constant if defined across the real number line. Every value of t corresponds to an event, and what if $f(t) = P(X)$ where X is the random variable and f is the PDF? I totally agree this question is horribly framed. I just wanted to know if it's even possible to salvage it.

Comment: I do not think they intend $f(t)$ to be a density.  If it were then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)dt = 1$ and so the the integral in (a) would always be 0.  I do not think there is any way to salvage this problem.  Note that your equation $f(t) = P[X]$ does not make sense as it has $t$ on the left but no $t$ on the right.  Also, it is incorrect to write $P[X]$ as that has no meaning in probability theory.  You can write $E[X]$ or $P[X>5]$ but certainly not $P[X]$.

Comment: @Michael oh thanks for that, that's a neat observation. And I finally get why it's the variance. If the random variable is $f(t)$ and it's probability density function is $g(f(t))$ Then the standard deviation is $E[(f(t)-0)^2]=\left [ \int f(t)^2 g(f(t))dt \right ]^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This summarizes the comments above, with perhaps some more info.

The integrals in (a)-(d) are commonly used in signal analysis, where the "signal" $f(t)$ is viewed as either a deterministic or stochastic function of time.  None of those integrals can be viewed as the "rapidity of change."

The integral in (a) is the sample path mean; the integral in (b) is the sample path second moment (which can be viewed as the sample path variance if we assume 0 mean); the quantity in (c) is just the square root of that of (b); (d) is a type of auto-correlation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation

I observe that if we use $f(t)=100$ for all $t$, there is no change in the function over time, so the "rapidity of change" is 0, but none of the integrals in (a)-(d) are 0.

I also observe that the integrals in (a)-(c) are the same if we replace $f(t)$ by $f(\lambda t)$, where $\lambda>0$ is a constant that can speed up or slow down time (i.e., $\lambda$ can directly affect "rapidity of change").   So certainly (a)-(c) have nothing to do with "rapidity of change" as they are not influenced by $\lambda$.  If I were forced to pick one of those choices, I would pick (d), since at least varying the $\tau$ parameter can tell you something about how the function changes over a duration of size $\tau$.